# Function with mongodb find does not return result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, swig-template

I am trying to return a Mongo result when I call a function in Swig template.  It does not wait for the mongo result and continues rendering the template.

Example code:

```
function swigfunction(){
  db.collection('contentitems').find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      //generated my output 
      return myoutput;
  });
}
```

Then I try to call the function, but "undefined" gets returned.

```
{{ swigfunction() }}
```

Please help

Comment: I think you need to learn the javascript basics first. Have a look how "scope" works and then google "callback", that is probably the very least you need here :)

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB API uses an asynchronous callback mechanism. That means instead of just idling and wasting resources, the program will continue while the database processes your request. When the response from the database finally arrives, the callback function `return myoutput;` is executed.

The usual pattern in node.js is to nest all your asynchronous function calls and write the output in the innermost callback function.

Comment: Thanks I understand that, but within Swig.js by the time the response has arrived from the database, Swig has already rendered the template.  I need to prevent the rendering and it should wait for the response first from the database.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't think you understand that - that function call won't contain the value of  `myoutput` - it doesn't work like PHP or other synchronous languages. That `return` won't return anything to `swigFunction`, it returns its value to the anonymous function that you call as your `find()` callback. As Philipp states, you need to learn how these functions work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongo-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sync) sync mongo-db client library.